# Internal error when debugging NDK app using NVidia Native Debugger

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, nvidia

I've got this error when launching the debugger within Eclipse using "Debug as NDK Application":

An internal error occurred during: "Launching STAAndroid".
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper.parseForData(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;)Lcom/android/sdklib/xml/ManifestData;

Any idea what happened here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need update ADT/NDK Plugin.